# How to write exponential representation

Tags: python

I would like to know how to write the equivalent representation to the following number in python:

```
-3.3999999521443642e+38
```

i did the following:

```
print(-3.3999999521443642*math.exp(38))
```

is it correct?

Comment: *"is it correct?"* - Well is it? Did it give you what you want when you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python supports the scientific notation just as you stated in your question with `e` in the number:

```
>>> a=-3.3999999521443642e+38
>>> print(a)
-3.3999999521443642e+38
>>> type(a)
<class 'float'>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use as is

```py
a = -3.3999999521443642e+38
print(a)
```

**output**
-3.3999999521443642e+38

Answer (score 0):

Python understands this representation directly.

```
x = 44e10
print (x)
440000000000.0
```

It is just an elegant way to represent big numbers in a compact way.